# Post double, string, and image as multipart form data using retrofit 2 in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to post double, string, and image Multipart Form Data using Retrofit 2 but with no success at all. I am constantly getting status code 400 errors. Searched in google but was not able to find the answer that works in my case. A screenshot of Swagger UI has been attached that works perfectly in the browser.

This is what I have tried so far in Kotlin:

```
interface IReportAPI {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/api/Reports")
    suspend fun postReport(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Part("AssignmentId") assignmentId: RequestBody?,
        @Part("MachineId") machineId: RequestBody?,
        @Part("Distance") distance: Double?,
        @Part("OriginalDistance") originalDistance: Double?,
        @Part("WorkedHours") workedHours: Double?,
        @Part("OriginalWorkedHours") originalWorkedHours: Double?,
        @Part("RouteImageFormFile") routeImageFormFile: RequestBody?
    ): JsonObject
}
```

This is service part:

```
        val assignmentID: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
            "79087c01-573a-a727-028d-d667bd54e236"
        )

        val machineID: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
            "39077c01-59a3-bc5a-8563-e9d63f1027d1")

        val fileUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://fi.gambitlabs.puhasworker/drawable/drawer_picture.png")
        val imgFile = File(fileUri.path)
        val requestBodyFile: RequestBody =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imgFile)

        // val assignmentID = "79087c01-573a-a727-028d-d667bd54e236" // tried with no success
        // val machineID = "39077c01-59a3-bc5a-8563-e9d63f1027d1"
        val distance = 10.0
        val originalDistance = 11.0
        val workedHours = 12.0
        val originalWorkedHours = 13.0

        message = reportService.postReport(authService.getAuth(token), assignmentID, machineID, distance, originalDistance, workedHours, originalWorkedHours, requestBodyFile)
```

All I get is status code 400. I am confused about how should I add double value in multipart/form data.

Comment: What does 400 mean?

Comment: Also use if (imgFile.exists()) before you continue assuming that the file exists.